# Phabricator - arc land throws an Exception due to a wrong git call

Tags: bug-tracking, phabricator

I am playing around with phabricator and recently ran into an issue with `arc land`:

I created a test-repository, did a commit and got it into phabricator with `arc diff`. Worked as expected. The commit lives under a branch called "new_feature".

In phabricator the diff was rejected for testing purposes. After rejecting, I tried `arc land`:

```
$ ~/git/test> git branch
   master
   * new_feature

$ ~/git/test> arc land
Landing current branch 'new_feature'.
Switched to branch master. Updating branch...
Exception
Command 'git pull --ff-only' failed with error #1:
stdout:

stderr:
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.master.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:

    [branch "master"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

Next step the reviewer accepted the patch but `arc land` threw the same Exception.
Ideas?

Comment: Well, I "fixed" it the q&d way by editing `arcanist/src/workflow/ArcanistLandWorkflow.php` and changing line 190 to: `$repository_api->execxLocal('pull --ff-only %s'.$remote.' '.$onto, '');`

Comment: That was even wrong. The right way is to setup the branch correctly like: `git branch --track new_feature origin/master`. With that done `arc land` works perfectly.

Comment: If the branch already exists, you need to use --set-upstream instead of --track.